# time count continue update when app is lock in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, timertask, timer-trigger

How can I count time in when the app is locked because I need to navigate to the screen after the second is over can anyone help me in this task

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you need to determine the lifecylestate if app is locked or not. You can have a look at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver/didChangeAppLifecycleState.html
How you use it is: Add `with WidgetsBindingObserver` to your Stateful Widget like

```
class _MyState extends State<MyStatefulWidget>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver
```

then use `didChangeAppLifecycleState` like this:

```
    @override
      void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
        super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
        switch (state) {
          case AppLifecycleState.resumed:    
            //make your operations        
            break;
          case AppLifecycleState.inactive: 
//make your operations          
            break;
          case AppLifecycleState.paused: 
//make your operations           
            break;
          case AppLifecycleState.detached: 
//make your operations          
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      }
```

When coming to counting time, look at `flutter_countdown_timer` package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_countdown_timer
Implement it and when app is paused, start your timer. When it finishes, do your operations and under resume, reset your countdown timer. Note that, you only need to write this in 1 of your StatefulWidgets, it works globally.